# "Put together" vs "Assemble"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, verbs, word-difference

As you know, the verb **"assemble"** means: "to make something by joining separate parts together"; also the phrasal verb **"put together"** means: "to put the parts of something in the correct places and join them to each other".

I need to know if they both can work in the same sense in the following sentence or not:

> - He helped his son to ............. his new model airplane.

a) put together 
b) assemble

I think both of the options "a" and "b" work naturally in the sentence above without any change in meaning.

Comment: Yes they do. I don't see any problems with both verbs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answer says, in the examples they are identical.

Note you can separate:

- He helped his son to **put** his new model airplane **together**.

But if it's not about a machine or something which is clearly made of pieces, there are cases where you can't use **assemble**.  In this case, most usually separated, **put together** means **put next to each other**:

- He **put** the tables **together** to make more space
- He **put** the German speakers **together** at the dinner table to make them more comfortable
- He **put together** a marvelous salad from leftovers

If you **assemble tables** it means make them from a kit (eg Ikea).
You can **assemble [people]** but here it means call a larger group together.  **Assemble** sounds unusual for food.

Comment: I might use "assemble" for a salad, particularly if I was stressing the complexity. I *would* use "We assembled a team of experts to solve the problem"

Comment: @DavidSiegel yes I think you're right, I've changed odd to unusual for salad.  Endives, chevre chaud, green pepporcorn vinaigrette, walnuts, _composée_!

Comment: Thank you @jonathanjo; but what about a car engine or a PC case? Do they mean the same when you're going to assemble/put together separated parts/pieces of a PC (e.g. motherboard,DVD drive, CPU, VGA etc.)? (The same goes for an automobile engine).

Comment: I'd use **assemble** for a computer, car engine or pretty much any kind of machinery.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both of those are perfectly natural in the sentence, and there is no significant meaning change. "Assemble" is slightly more formal. In a technical discussion of, say the inventions of Henry Ford, I would expect to see "assemble" rather than "put together". But I can't think of a context where one would be acceptable and the other wrong, nor ojne where the meaning would be very different.